# How to group by comma delimited column in mssql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables with

T1(user)

```
Id  Name CourseIds

1   Joel  1,2,3 
2   Jeff  2,3,4
```

T2(courses)

```
CourseId CourseName

1         C# 
2         Javascript
3         SQL
4         VB
```

I have to join the two tables and find out the count of each courses - learned by a user (group by) like
(result table)

```
Courses      Count

C#           1  
Javascript   2
SQL          2
VB           1
```

I have tried stackoverflow answers related to the question but they din't help. Please help me.

Comment: maybe first renormalize the database correctly so that each item is in its own row.  then this and many other queries will become trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should fix your data structure.  Storing lists of ids in a comma delimited list is bad for many reasons:

- Storing numbers as strings is bad.
- Storing multiple values in a single field is bad.
- Not being able to declare foreign key relationships is bad.
- Such lists cannot take advantage of indexes.
- Junction tables are a much better alternative.

Sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really bad decisions.  If this is the case, you can do what you want, although not efficiently:

```
select c.coursename,
       (select count(*)
        from user u
        where ',' + u.courseids + ',' like '%,' + cast(c.id as varchar(255)) + ',%'
       ) as cnt
from courses c;
```

But really, rather than putting together arcane string operations, it is better to fix the data structure.

Comment: I have tried the above but it gives C# -1, Javascript - 2, SQL - 1, VB - 0. Anything I want to change ?? Not like my result set.

Comment: @Prashanth . . . It works fine in SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3e655/1.

Answer (score 1):

```
With cte(courseids,si,ei)
As(
 Select courseids,
              1,
             charindex(',', courseids)
   From user

Union all

Select courseids,
            Cast( 1 +ei as int),
            Charindex(',',courseids,1+ei)
From cte 
Where ei >0
)
Select substring(courseids,si, case when ei>0 then ei- si else Len(courseids) end) as courseid into #t 
From cte;

Select count(1) as count, (select coursename from courses where courseid = t.courseid) as courses
From #t t
Group by courseid;
Drop table #t;
```

Answer (score 1):

late to answer but you can proceed like this also

```
     DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Id int, Name varchar(4), CourseIds varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Id, Name, CourseIds)
VALUES
    (1, 'Joel', '1,2,3'),
    (2, 'Jeff', '2,3,4')
;

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE 
    (CourseId int, CourseName varchar(10))
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    (CourseId, CourseName)
VALUES
    (1, 'C#'),
    (2, 'Javascript'),
    (3, 'SQL'),
    (4, 'VB')
;


declare @str varchar(max)

;with cte as (
SELECT    Id,Name,
     Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Courseid  
 FROM  (SELECT  Id,Name, 
         CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([CourseIds], ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS String  
     FROM  @Table1) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))

     select TT.CourseName,COUNT(C.Courseid) AS Courseid from cte C
     INNER JOIN @Table2 TT
     ON TT.CourseId = C.Courseid
     GROUP BY TT.CourseName
```

Comment: @prasanth can you check out the answer